# See if message is read/unread in Sinch messaging

Tags: parse-platform, instant-messaging, sinch

I'm using Sinch! Instant Messaging together with Parse-server in my application. Is there a good way to mark a message object as "read" without actually first saving it to the backend, and then pulling it down on the other side and mark is at read, and then re-saving it to the same backend, but now as "read" instead of "unread"? 
I want the users to be able to see if they have read a message or not, so new message are highlighted. Is there an easy way to do this with Sinch? Or any suggestions on how to do this effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we dont have read, but i dont see why you would need to save it to your backend first. I would mark them as read locally as soon as they are in you IM view

Comment: My thought would be that the one who sends the msg, would send a "unread" message that will be saved to the backend just in case the other user is not online/in the app at all. Then the other user could see a unread message when he/she logs on. If the other user is actually online, this user would have to fetch the same message object somehow, and then mark it as "read" and then save it to the backend so he would not se it as "unread" next time he/she visits the app.

Comment: But yeah I guess it would be more clever to just have it saved locally

Comment: The user would probably get a push from us/you about unread right? Just treat all messages that are not "read" as unread and you should be good to go. Thanks for marking it answered!

Comment: Yeah, send the push and all messages are unread. And then we just handle the "read" tag locally as you suggested. Works well!